# No visible @interface for 'WKInterfaceController' declares the selector 'initWithContext:'

Tags: ios, xcode6, watchkit

From the last Xcode beta i've got an error in all my project and in all my sample code , also as in Apple Sample code like Lister app !

> No visible @interface for 'WKInterfaceController' declares the
>   selector 'initWithContext:'

[image]

Where is the problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make sure your super class has that method declaration with same method signature. Hope this helps.. :)

If you look at [WKInterfaceController document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html) you can't see any  method named `initWithContext`. Apple said;

> The WKInterfaceController method initWithContext: has been deprecated.
>   Please use awakeWithContext: instead. The designated initializer for
>   WKInterfaceController is now init.

You should use :

```
self = [super init];
```

Not:

```
self = [super initWithContext:context];
```

Comment: Excuse Rashad if I'm an idiot , but where I must declarate it ? In .h? How ? Another question: in the previous beta I haven't this error , why ? Thank you so much!!

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html

Is there ant method named initWithContext?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
self = [super initWithContext:context];
```

use

```
self = [super init];
```

Answer (score 3):

From Apple's Docs, this was changed between beta's:

> The WKInterfaceController method initWithContext: has been deprecated. Please use awakeWithContext: instead. The designated initializer for WKInterfaceController is now init.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.2/index.html